# Thymeleaf templatespring boot jpa can't get data fom the dabase,404 error

Tags: spring, web, thymeleaf

```
: Resource not found
2019-07-29 05:04:25.834 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2019-07-29 05:04:25.834 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2019-07-29 05:04:25.834 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2019-07-29 05:04:25.834 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2019-07-29 05:04:25.834 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Mon Jul 29 05:04:25 PDT 2019, status=404, error=Not Found, message=No message available,  (truncated)...]
2019-07-29 05:04:25.835 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
2019-07-29 05:04:37.741 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/favicon.ico", parameters={}
2019-07-29 05:04:37.742 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/], class path resource []]
2019-07-29 05:04:37.754 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

The problem is data already exist in the database but it's not being displayed in HTML table

EmployerController.java

```
package io.javabrains;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.hibernate.mapping.Index;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.javabrains.Entity.Employer;

@Controller
public class EmployerController {


    @Autowired
    private EmployerService service;




    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String newForm() {
        return "form1";
    }






     public List<Employer>getAllEmployers()
     {


        return  service.getAllEmployers();



     }

        @RequestMapping(value="/tables",method=RequestMethod.GET)

    public String getAllEmployers(Model model)
    {
         List<Employer>employers = service.getAllEmployers(); 
        model.addAttribute("Employer",employers);
        return "tables";
    }





      @RequestMapping("/employer/{id}") 
      public Employer getEmployer(@PathVariable Integer id) { 
          return service.getEmployers(id);
      }



    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/employer")
    public void addEmployer(@RequestBody Employer employer) {
        service.addEmployer(employer);

    }


    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT,value="/employer/{id}")
    public void updateEmployer(@RequestBody Employer employer,@PathVariable int id) {
        service.updateEmployer(id,employer);
    }




      @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE,value="/create/{id}") 
     public void deleteEmployer(@PathVariable int id)
     {
          service.deleteEmployer(id);
     }
```

EmployerService.java

```
package io.javabrains;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import io.javabrains.Entity.Employer;

@Service
public class EmployerService {
    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;

    public List<Employer>getAllEmployers(){
        List<Employer>employers = new ArrayList<>();
        repository.findAll()
        .forEach(employers::add);
        return employers;

    }

    public void addEmployer(Employer employer) {
        repository.save(employer);
    }


    public void updateEmployer(int id, Employer employer) {
        repository.save(employer);
    }


    public void deleteEmployer(int id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
        ;
    }



      public Employer getEmployers(int id) 
      { 
          return repository.getOne(id);

      }





}
```

Employer.Java

```
package io.javabrains;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import io.javabrains.Entity.Employer;

@Service
public class EmployerService {
    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;

    public List<Employer>getAllEmployers(){
        List<Employer>employers = new ArrayList<>();
        repository.findAll()
        .forEach(employers::add);
        return employers;

    }

    public void addEmployer(Employer employer) {
        repository.save(employer);
    }


    public void updateEmployer(int id, Employer employer) {
        repository.save(employer);
    }


    public void deleteEmployer(int id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
        ;
    }



      public Employer getEmployers(int id) 
      { 
          return repository.getOne(id);

      }





}
```

table.html

```
<tbody>
                    <tr th:each="$(employers)">
                      <td th:text="${employers.name}"></td>
                      <td th:text="${employer.position}"></td>
                      <td th:text="${employer.office}"></td>
                      <td th:text="${employer.age}"></td>
                     <td th:text="${employer.salary}"></td>
                    </tr>
```

......

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the method you are testing is this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/tables",method=RequestMethod.GET)

    public String getAllEmployers(Model model)
{
     List<Employer>employers = service.getAllEmployers(); 
    model.addAttribute("Employer",employers);
    return "tables";
}
```

for the `tables.html` file you should have something like this

```
 <tr th:each="${Employer}">
```

matching the name attribute with your html file.

Plus, at your service you can just do

```
repository.findAll()
```

This guide might help you https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation